# Connection refused from docker (in swarm)

Tags: java, docker, networking, docker-swarm

I have a docker swarm setup with services registered in an overlay network. Comunication between services is working fine however I get a "Connection refused" from one of my services that connects to an external DB. The service is a Java based application (spring boot).

- The connection is defined with its IP (jdbc:mysql://192.168.130.141:3306/database?autoReconnect=true)
- I have checked that I can ping the server from the container `docker exec -it e093 ping 192.168.130.141` gives expected answer
- I have rechecked (4 times) my credentials
- I can connect to the DB from the host
- Host is Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

I am running docker 18.03.0-ce and the exact error is

`java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]`

I'll skip the full stack trace here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**--EDIT--**

Let me clarify that the database is a Galera cluster and the IP I try to connect to is the load balancer (HAProxy) in front of it. I know the setup works as I have other applications connecting to the cluster in this matter as well as the service itself (when not in a docker container).

So, as far as I can tell, my connection informations are correct but it doesn't connect from inside docker services.

Comment: Can you telnet also to the ip on 3306 from inside the container?

Comment: Are your MySQL listening on 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I have tried to telnet but it is not installed in the images I have

Comment: @Yuankun The setup is a bit more complex than that. Meaning that it is a cluster going through the proxy. However, I can confirm that the proxy does not receive any connection requests

Answer (score -1):

Can you  show your docker-compose.yml? In the ports you have to expose the port that you need to access.

```
ports:
   - 3306:3306
```

You can install telnet to test if the port is open using this commands inside the container

```
docker container ls
docker exec -it conainerid bash
apt-get update
apt-get install telnet
```